# EMET Configuration refresh

Tags: windows, group-policy

I deployed EMET on my domain and i'm configuring it with a GPO.
I'd like to know if the system settings *System DEP, System ASLR and System SEHOP* are taken into account when i refresh the group policies or do i need to also refresh EMET's configuration (*emet_conf --refresh*)?
Thank you for your answers.